# run cron job web2py under pythonanywhere

Tags: python, web2py

let take a example , i want to run a mail function from scheduler. i made mail.py under the modules

```
from gluon.tools import Mail
    mail=Mail()
    mail.settings.server='smtp.gmail.com:587'
    mail.settings.login='ass.aa@gmail.com:aaaaaa'
    mail.settings.sender='aaa.aa@aa.com'
    mail.send(to=['aaa@aaa.a,'],
    subject='aaaaaa',
    message='<html>'
            '<body>'
                            'test mail'
                        '</body>'
                    '</html>')
```

my corntab file is

```
0-59/1  *  *  *  * root *applications/comv1/modules/mail1.py
```

scheduler.py file which under home > application name of pythonanywhwer

```
#/usr/bin/env python
import os
import socket
import sys
import subprocess
filename = os.path.abspath(__file__)  # we use this to generate a unique socket name
try:
    socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM).bind('\0' + filename)
except socket.error:
    print("Failed to acquire lock, task must already be running")
    sys.exit()
subprocess.call(["python", "web2py/web2py.py", "-K", "comv3"])
```

after this also i am not able to run cron job.....

can any one help me

Answer (score 2):

PythonAnywhere does not read crontab. If you want to run a task periodically, we provide Scheduled tasks. There are docs about how to use them on our help pages.